# How to use Highcharts in React-Native using webview?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-native

I want to render a chart inside a webview in react-Native.
I used highcharts npm package.

I defined a Webview something like this

```
<WebView  ref='webview' />
```

In componentDidMount, I wrote

```
 componentDidMount(){

    var chart = Highcharts.chart(this.refs.webview,{
        series: [{
          data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
        }],
          // ... more options - see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts 
      });
}
```

But it is throwing error.

Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: React-native throws error Highcharts.chart is not a function

Comment: Have you imported Highcharts properly? can you console.log(Highcharts)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `react-native-highcharts` or `highcharts-react-native` npm packages. It does this for you with a `ChartView` component in react-native-highcharts and a `HigchchartsReactNative` component in `highcharts-react-native`. I think you are writing the code for `react-highcharts` and attempting to put it in a `WebView`. I don't recommend this. Here are a few links

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/creating-mobile-charts-with-highcharts-react-native/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highcharts

The main difference is that `react-native-highcharts` is a third party package that supports most of highcharts products like `highstock` or `highmaps` while `highcharts-react-native` only support `highcharts`.

Comment: please consider including more of your answer here instead of just linking to documentation.

Comment: Duly noted, to install ```npm install react-native-highcharts --save``` or ```npm install @highcharts/highcharts-react-native``` and the components are implemented like `<ChartView style={{height:300}} config={conf} options={options}></ChartView>` and  `<HighchartsReactNative styles {styles.container} options={this.state.chartOptions}/>`